# In magento 2 how to display a form fields in under payment method

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, field

In magento 2  how to display a form fields in under payment method 
[image]

Comment: Do you want this after specific payment method?

Comment: Checkout is hard place to modify. Use extension like this https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-checkout-custom-field-extension.html although lots out there